# "Scope Must Be API" when making Send on Behalf Curl Request

Tags: docusignapi

Following the docs here: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo

I have built the following curl request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=<my integrator key>username=<my email>&password=<my password>&scope=api' \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-length: 0' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
```

However, when I run this, I get this response

```
{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "Scope must be 'api'."
}
```

I get the same thing when I run a similar call in nodejs

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/token',
  qs:
   { grant_type: 'password',
     client_id: '',
     username: '',
     password: '',
     scope: 'api' },
  headers:
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-length': '0',
     accept: 'application/json',
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

I have also tried using this url, but get an "Object moved" response: https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2/oauth2/token

Which doesn't make sense to me, because I do have "scope=api" right at the end of the url.  What is going on here?

Comment: Looks like you've included your login credentials in your code sample. I'd suggest that you change your password immediately (via the DocuSign web console) and update the code sample to not include actual username/password.

Comment: Thanks Kim!  Advice heeded.  Can you also comment on the problem here as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of searching, I have discovered this (contradictory) doc: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html

Turns out you do not need to do the multi-step OAuth token process like is outlined in the first link I shared.  You simply need a 'SendOnBehalfOf' parameter in your X-DocuSign-Authentication header.

Taken directly from that link, it will look like this:

```
{
  "Username": "nat.irving@example.com",
  "Password": "S3cre+p455w0Rd",
  "IntegratorKey": "230546a7-9c55-40ad-8fbf-af205d5494ad",
  "SendOnBehalfOf": "ruggiero.gardener@example.com"
}
```